# boto3 python lambda extracting values from json response

Tags: python, boto3

A newbie here. I'm trying to workout how I should go about extracting some specific values from a json output produced upon executing a particular boto3 method. Below is the code that works;

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('apigateway')
    response = client.get_usage_plans()['items']
    return response
```

Above gives me the below output as expected.

```
Response:
[
  {
    "id": "p90xvt",
    "name": "Basic",
    "apiStages": [
      {
        "apiId": "g1gckiw2cj",
        "stage": "prod"
      }
    ],
    "quota": {
      "limit": 10,
      "offset": 0,
      "period": "DAY"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "rt9k2q",
    "name": "Prem",
    "apiStages": [
      {
        "apiId": "g1gckiw2cj",
        "stage": "prod"
      }
    ],
    "quota": {
      "limit": 10,
      "offset": 0,
      "period": "DAY"
    }
  }
]

Request ID:
"4aa80ca1-c48d-11e8-95cf-f59e9444b72c"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 4aa80ca1-c48d-11e8-95cf-f59e9444b72c Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 4aa80ca1-c48d-11e8-95cf-f59e9444b72c
REPORT RequestId: 4aa80ca1-c48d-11e8-95cf-f59e9444b72c  Duration: 631.18 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 31 MB
```

What I'm struggling to understand is that how to extract some specific key:values from the output? Say If I want to print YES if the limit of a quota belongs to a specific id(i.e:"p90xvt") equals to 10? Mind you I need to cover all ids.

Really appreciate your help on this people. 
Many thanks in advance. 
-B

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're trying to do. You have a list of dicts, so you can access the values like this: `d=response[0]; print(d["id"], d["quota"]["limit"])`

Answer (score 1):

```
 for field in response:
        if field['quota']['limit']==10:
            print (field['id'])
```